# Pandas nested loop which checks if values from one series are in another series

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I have two different series in pandas that I have created a nested for loop which checks if the values of the first series are in the other series. But this is time consuming in pandas and I cannot work out how to change it to a pandas method. I thought to use the `apply` function but it did not work with method chaining. My original nested for loops look like so and they work;

```py
for x in df_one['ser_one']:
    print(x)
    for y in df_two['ser_two']:
        if 'MBTS' not in y and x in y:
            if 'L' in y:
                print(y)
```

Is there a way to make this less time consuming?

Here is what I attempted using `apply` methods;

```
df_two['ser_two'].apply(lambda x: x if 'MBTS' not in df_one['ser_one'].apply(lambda y:y) and x in df_one['ser_one'].apply(lambda y:y))
```

---

Example input:

```
df_one.head()
Out[136]: 
   type   ser_one
0  MBTS  VUMX1234
1  MBTS  VUMX6436
2  MBTS  VUMX5745
3  MBTS  VUMX5802
4  MBTS  VUMX8091
```

```
df_two.head()
Out[137]: 
     ser_two    
0  VUMX8091    
1  VUMX8091L    
2  VUMX1234    
3  VUMX1234L    
4  VUMX5838
```

Comment: Can you add some example input?

Comment: @Graipher have added.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer, I am not the best at pandas, and I'm absolutely sure there is a far more readable way to accomplish this, but the following will rid you of your for loop and nested if statements, which are slower than vectorized numpy/pandas operations.

Your filter `if 'MBTS' not in y` won't work the way you think it will, at least, given the limited sample input, as `y` is a Series made from the column `ser_one`, not `type`. Let's assume that's an easy fix so in pseudocode it should be something like:

```
for x in df_one.ser_one:
    for y in df_two: # iterate through the rows so you get both columns
        if 'MBTS' not in y.type and x in y.ser_two:
            if 'L' not in y.ser_two:
                print(y)
```

This is a bit clunky, and pandas is great for vectorizing these sorts of operations, so let's filter it down to just `Series` operations. I'm working with a small part of your dataframes, so as a sanity check, they look like

```
df_one
     ser_one  type
0   VUMX1234  MBTS
1   VUMX6436  MBTS
2   VUMX5745  MBTS
3   VUMX5802  MBTS
4   VUMX8091  MBTS
5   VUMX1234  XXXX
6  VUMX1234L  XXXX

df_two
     ser_two
0   VUMX8091
1  VUMX8091L
2   VUMX1234
3  VUMX1234L
4   VUMX5838
```

I added a few entries that were non-MBTS to fit your problem.

The first bit, you want to find where `'MBTS'` is not in `df_one.type`, but we want to filter the *entire* dataframe for that. `df.loc` will give you the rows that pass a given filter:

```py
df_one.loc[df_one['type'] == 'MBTS']
    ser_one  type
0  VUMX1234  MBTS
1  VUMX6436  MBTS
2  VUMX5745  MBTS
3  VUMX5802  MBTS
4  VUMX8091  MBTS

# or
df_one.loc[df_one['type'] != 'MBTS']
     ser_one  type
5   VUMX1234  XXXX
6  VUMX1234L  XXXX
```

Now you can check if the results of `ser_one` are contained within `ser_two`, since the output of that previous check is a `Series`, like so:

```py
df_one.loc[df_one['type'] != 'MBTS']['ser_one'].isin(df_two['ser_two'])
5    True
6    True
```

Just get the `.loc` back from that, and you should be left with two records in this example:

```py
df_one.loc[df_one.loc[df_one['type'] != 'MBTS']['ser_one'].isin(df_two['ser_two']).index]
     ser_one  type
5   VUMX1234  XXXX
6  VUMX1234L  XXXX
```

It might be a bit easier to do the filtering against any `ser_one` that contains `'L'` ahead of time:

```py
df_one[~df_one['ser_one'].str.contains("L")]
    ser_one  type
0  VUMX1234  MBTS
1  VUMX6436  MBTS
2  VUMX5745  MBTS
3  VUMX5802  MBTS
4  VUMX8091  MBTS
5  VUMX1234  XXXX
```

Now, combining all of that into one big gigantic horrible expression

```py
df_one.loc[df_one[~df_one['ser_one'].str.contains("L")].loc[df_one['type'] != 'MBTS']['ser_one'].isin(df_two['ser_two']).index]

    ser_one  type
5  VUMX1234  XXXX
```

The outer `loc` will take an array of index values as returned by the `.index` call near the end of the expression. The rest is just chained filters which are operations in native pandas, implemented in C and fast.